# Match multiple components of a subquery CTE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, subquery, cte

I've got an app that grants access to users in varying different ways, and I'm attempting to write a query that determines access in all the different ways, but is readable, by breaking the access out into CTEs.

This is the basic pattern I'm talking about:

```
WITH user_allowed_data1 AS (
    SELECT u.id user_id, c.id content_id FROM …
),
user_allowed_data2 AS (
    SELECT u.id user_id, c.id content_id FROM …
)
SELECT u.name, c.name FROM user_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN content_table ON 1=1
WHERE u.id, c.id in (SELECT user_id, content_id FROM user_allowed_data_1)
OR u.id, c.id in (SELECT user_id, content_id FROM user_allowed_data_2)
```

So, two questions:

1. Is there a better/faster/cleaner way to think about this query?
2. Is there a way to match multiple fields pulled out of a subquery in a where clause like that?

Comment: Why this convoluted way of joining? It seems you want a (ok, not very simple but more than yours) `FROM user_table JOIN user_allowed_data_1 ON .. JOIN user_allowed_data_2 ON ... JOIN content_table ON ...;` (and no`WHERE` clause) **Oh.** I missed the `OR`, ignore this.

Comment: And I suppose the 2 CTEs are different. Right?

Comment: If you only use the CTEs once, then I'd write them as "ordinary" subqueries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to rewrite the query, even with keeping the CTEs. But please consider that CTEs in Postgres are pre-evaluated, so they might cause efficiency problems.

- first, the `LEFT` join is equivalent to an inner `JOIN`, as you have a column from the right-side table in the following `WHERE` clause.
- second, the `FROM user_table LEFT OUTER JOIN content_table ON 1=1` is awkward. You could use the simple `FROM user_table CROSS JOIN content_table`. Not any performance gain, just more simple. I think I would prefer even the (frawned upon) `FROM user_table, content_table` from the `LEFT ... ON 1=1`.
- after doing that, it's easy to see that `FROM a CROSS JOIN b WHERE <x>` can be replace with `FROM a JOIN b ON <x>`
- the `IN (SELECT user_id, content_id FROM user_allowed_data_1)` can be replaced with the more elegant `IN (TABLE user_allowed_data_1)`

Now, to get rid of the `OR`, one way would be to combine the two ctes in one:

```
-- query 1 --
WITH user_allowed_data AS (
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, c.id AS content_id FROM …
  UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, c.id AS content_id FROM …
)
SELECT u.name, c.name 
FROM user_table AS u
  JOIN content_table AS c 
    ON (u.id, c.id) IN (TABLE user_allowed_data) ;
```

But since we did that, we can just use joins in the main query and not the fancy `ON ... IN (...)`:

```
-- query 2 --
WITH user_allowed_data AS (
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, c.id AS content_id FROM …
  UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, c.id AS content_id FROM …
)
SELECT u.name, c.name 
FROM user_table AS u
  JOIN user_allowed_data AS ad
    ON ad.user_id = u.id
  JOIN content_table AS c 
    ON ad.content_id = c.id ;
```

Another way - to get rid of the `OR` - would be to use `UNION` in the main query instead:

```
-- query 3 --
WITH user_allowed_data1 AS (
    SELECT u.id user_id, c.id content_id FROM …
),
user_allowed_data2 AS (
    SELECT u.id user_id, c.id content_id FROM …
)
SELECT u.name, c.name 
FROM user_table AS u
  JOIN user_allowed_data1 AS ad
    ON ad.user_id = u.id
  JOIN content_table AS c 
    ON ad.content_id = c.id 
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT u.name, c.name 
FROM user_table AS u
  JOIN user_allowed_data2 AS ad
    ON ad.user_id = u.id
  JOIN content_table AS c 
    ON ad.content_id = c.id ;
```

Any of the above of course can be written without ctes - which I stress again - can be a barrier to efficiency. So, your original query, slightly altered and without CTEs (keeping the `OR`):

```
-- query 1b --
SELECT u.name, c.name 
FROM user_table AS u
  JOIN content_table AS c 
    ON (u.id, c.id) IN (SELECT u.id AS user_id, c.id AS content_id FROM …)
    OR (u.id, c.id) IN (SELECT u.id AS user_id, c.id AS content_id FROM …) ;
```

The `OR` variants can also be expressed by replacing the `IN` with a correlated `EXISTS` subquery:

```
-- query 1c --
SELECT uu.name, cc.name 
FROM user_table AS uu
  JOIN content_table AS cc 
    ON EXISTS (SELECT u.id AS user_id, c.id AS content_id FROM …
               WHERE (u.id, c.id) = (uu.id, cc.id) )
    OR EXISTS (SELECT u.id AS user_id, c.id AS content_id FROM …
               WHERE (u.id, c.id) = (uu.id, cc.id) ) ;
```

Comment: I'd rather use an `OR`. I know this smells of the old "`not in` is slow" adage, but I usually find a query with two subqueries ORed together faster than the alternative with a `UNION` in a single subquery.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Of course. If the 2 ctes produced (or could be altered to produce non-duplicate results), I'd be inclined more to a `UNION ALL` version. (And testing various ways doesn't hurt).